# fail2ban block plex failed login attempts

Tags: ubuntu, regex, fail2ban

I want to ban IPs who attempt to authenticate against my public Plex instance.

Im on Ubuntu and the log Im looking at is the following:

```
/var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application\ Support/Plex\ Media\ Server/Logs/Plex\ Media\ Server.log
```

Filter

```
[Definition]
failregex = .*\[\d*\].*Completed: \[<HOST>\:.*401 GET.*
```

Sample Log lines

```
May 19, 2023 10:32:08.127 [140346159979320] DEBUG - Completed: [1.2.3.4:45528] 401 GET / (3 live) #d130 GZIP 0ms 435 bytes
May 19, 2023 13:38:38.252 [140346093181752] DEBUG - Request: [1.2.3.5:58892 (Subnet)] GET /:/prefs (12 live) #d201 TLS GZIP Signed-in Token (username) (Chrome)
```

As you can see Im trying to block the IP of the line that has the `401` response but when I test the filter with `fail2ban-regex` I always get `0 matched`. What am I missing?